# CSV Reader not working anymore... without making any changes

Tags: c#, csvhelper

I have a little app that is working for a month now. I made absolute no changes to the code of this part and from one moment to the other the app stops working.

I even tried old files that I already imported in the past. No rights issue. Same drive. I can open all files. No changes at all in the files.

The error is always:

> CsvHelper.HeaderValidationException: "Header with name 'Betrag der Rate' was not found.

How can I solve this?

```
if (filename != string.Empty)
{
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(filename))
    using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
    {

        csv.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<LastschriftMap>();
        csv.Configuration.HasHeaderRecord = true;

        var records = csv.GetRecords<Lastschriften>();
        alleLastschriften = records.ToList();
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: you just refer it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47024481/c-sharp-csvhelper-validationexception-why

Comment: Chaning the Seperator is leading into an Error that he is not able to Convert the DateTime of one Field. No chance to find out of which field. Rechecked it. All CSV Files of the last year had ALL the ";" as seperator and it always worked like a charme. Also no changes on the DateTime Format.

Answer (score 0):

If this is reading German data, try using `CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("de-DE")` instead of `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`.  Or use `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` which was the default in the past.